# Pythonの正規表現で使用しているパーセント記号は何？

Tags: python, 正規表現

下記のコードで`%`の部分は何をしているのでしょうか？

**該当部分**

```
l_regex = re.compile(r'^%s*' % character[0])
r_regex = re.compile(r'%s*$' % character[0])
```

**コード全体**

```
import re

def strip_text(text, *character):
    if character:
        print(character)
        l_regex = re.compile(r'^%s*' % character[0])
        r_regex = re.compile(r'%s*$' % character[0])
    else:
        l_regex = re.compile(r'^\s*')
        r_regex = re.compile(r'\s*$')
    text = l_regex.sub('', text)
    text = r_regex.sub('', text)
    print(text)

strip_text('    前後のスペース文字を取り除く    ')
strip_text('XXXX前後のXを取り除くXXXX', 'X')
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのプログラムは何らかの資料に載っていたものでしょうか？　もしそうであれば著作権の問題があるかもしれないため、可能であれば引用元を明記して頂きたいです。質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、そちらからよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4):

これは文字列をフォーマット文字列として扱って置換しています。`%`形式の文字列フォーマットです。`%s` が後から渡された文字列に置換されています。

```
>>> 'aaa%sbbb' % 'あ'
'aaaあbbb'
>>> 'aaa%sbbb' % 'い'
'aaaいbbb'
```

このコードの場合は、与えられた文字列の1文字目 `character[0]` ごとに動的に正規表現を作るためにフォーマット文字列を使っています。

なお、`%`を使って文字列をフォーマットするのは現在では古いやり方で、f文字列を使う新しいやり方があります。2016年の記事ですが[「Pythonの新しい文字列フォーマット : %記号、str.format()から文字列補完へ」](https://postd.cc/new-string-formatting-in-python/)などを参照してください。

Comment: "{}".format()とは別な手段があるのですね、参考になりました。